# sharepoint workflow

Tags: sharepoint

I am new this sharepoint development and i have task in hand to do the following.
1.When a new document added to the library, the system will prompt for approvers & audience from a database table. this will be stored for future revisions for the document.
2. Upon successful completion of assigning approvers, audience the system will initiate the workflow to complete the approval process.

It would be great if anyone can point the direction to do the following:
1.is it possible to call a aspx page/form from document library insert/update event?
2.How to assign approvers to a workflow programmatically?

Thanks in Advance!
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I'm not sure it is possible to explicitly call another page but you can use the "Source" url parameter to specify the page they are directed to after they press OK. Obviously, you will have to change "www.google.com" to be your new URL.

   /Lists/Announcements/NewForm.aspx?Source=www.google.com
2. You can probably do all of this using custom workflow. With custom workflow you have two options: creating the entire workflow in visual studio or create custom workflow actions and using SharePoint Designer to build the workflow.

[Building custom Workflow Actions.](http://www.johnholliday.net/post/2007/03/27/Add-Your-Own-Custom-Workflow-Activities-to-SharePoint-Designer-2007.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Kit... i am still researching what are the best way to do this using out of the box templates and lists with minimal changes. i'll update this when i get implemented successfully.